# use cpp.vim to chage the highlight (vim of ubuntu)

Tags: c++, vim

I fell that the highlight in vim is not as powerful as I want. such as "&&","||" these can not be highlighted. I know it can be changed by cpp.vim but I don not know how to do it. Can someone tell me how to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If default highlight options does not suits you, try some custom plug-in before trying to write your own, most of plug-ins are located on github e.g.

https://github.com/octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight

Maybe you should start with one on vim plug-in managers first e.g.

https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim